# Oracle APEX - converting a field from collection to type DATE

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page that grabs data from apex collection and one of the fields is date but since it is coming from collection it comes up as text. What is the best way to convert it to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, *text* (string) is converted to DATE with TO_DATE function, by applying the correct format mask. For example:

```
SQL> with test (text_value) as
  2    (select '23.04.2019' from dual union all
  3     select '04-2019-23' from dual union all
  4     select '04 April 2019' from dual
  5    )
  6  select to_date(text_value, 'dd.mm.yyyy') result from test
  7  where text_value = '23.04.2019'
  8  union all
  9  select to_date(text_value, 'mm-yyyy-dd') from test
 10  where text_Value = '04-2019-23'
 11  union all
 12  select to_date(text_value, 'dd month yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english')
 13  from test
 14  where text_value = '04 April 2019'
 15  /

RESULT
----------
23/04/2019
23/04/2019
04/04/2019

SQL>
```